# Flask Blueprints sharing

Tags: flask, blueprint

I want to make an API with Flask and it also needs to have an admin panel.
I guess that Blueprints are the way to go, but I don't want to make models twice.

My structure is going to be this:

`- app
  - api
  - admin
  - models`

So my question is: How can I access the models in the `models` folder in my `api` blueprint and my `admin` blueprint?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

if you'd in a module within the `api` or `admin` folders you can import anything from a module in the `models` folder using this notation

```
from ..models.module_name import model1, model2, etc
```

for small projects i usually keep all the models in a single models.py file like:

```
[app]
  [blueprint_1]
     __init__.py
     views.py
  [blueprint_2]
  [static]
  [templates]
  __init__.py
  models.py
```

then from within any of your blueprint files just:

```
from ..models import model1, model2, etc
```

Comment: Thanks , I thought that import was from within the current folder and without going back.

Comment: No problem, hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

About the import, If your directory include `__init__.py` then it is a python package so `.` use for current dir. For example:

```
auth/ 
     __init__.py 
     forms.py 
     views.py 
#views.py
from forms import Form name 
from . import auth_blueprint # imports from __init__.py
```

So if you wants to import from another directory you have to use `..` to imports from `__init__.py` file let's say your models directory include those files :

```
models/ 
    __init__.py 
    UserModel.py
```

Now let's import models for auth module :

```
#auth/views.py 
from .. import models # import froms models/__init__.py 
from ..models import UserModel
```